# Would subtracting sensor TYPE_GRAVITY readings from TYPE_ACCELEROMETER readings result in TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION readings?

Tags: android, sensors, accelerometer, gravity

I've made the mistake of using the regular TYPE_ACCELEROMETER sensor to record some sensor readings, however I needed to use the TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor instead.

If I also have TYPE_GRAVITY sensor data that was recorded alongside the TYPE_ACCELEROMETER data, would simply subtracting the TYPE_GRAVITY readings from the TYPE_ACCELEROMETER data result in what using the TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor would have given?